# test if row NULL values in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to delete row if in the same line i have id1 and id2 are empty.
I did these lines but got error.

```
d = {'id1': ['Y22', 'X23', None], 'id2': ['Y10', "Y14", None], 'id3':[77,22,13]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df[df[pd.notnull(df['id1'])and df[pd.notnull(df['id2'])]]
```

Comment: `df[~(df['id1'].isna() & df['id2'].isna())]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`df.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) on `axis=1` and check if all values in `id1` and `id2` are not null, then use it as boolean mask:

```
df[~df[['id1','id2']].isna().all(axis=1)]
```

---

```
   id1  id2  id3
0  Y22  Y10   77
1  X23  Y14   22
```

Comment: Thank you but it not what i want i want to delete just when the two values in the same row are NULL.

Comment: @Miss so if both the `ids` are `None` dont select the row? Can you test again?